# Defining a property getter for my singleton class in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, singleton, coffeescript, getter

This is a helper function I define for creating properties in my classes:

```
###
# defines a property on an object/class
# modified from https://gist.github.com/746380
###
Object::public = (name, options = {}) ->
  options['default'] ?= null
  variable = options['default']
  getter = if typeof options['get'] is 'function' then options['get'] else -> variable
  setter = if typeof options['set'] is 'function' then options['set'] else (value) ->  variable = value

  config = {}
  config['get'] = getter if options['get']
  config['set'] = setter if options['set']
  config['configurable'] = no
  config['enumerable'] = yes

  Object.defineProperty @prototype, name, config
```

Inside a file I have the two classes below, Folds and _Folds, the latter being hidden with only the former exported (namespaced) to the global.

```
###
  Public exported fetcher for fold factory,
  being the only way through which to create folds.
###
class Folds
  _instance = undefined

  # static fetch property method
  @public 'Factory',
    get: -> _instance ?= new _Folds

###
  Encapsuled singleton factory for one-stop fold creation
###
class _Folds
  constructor: ->

  create: -> new Fold
```

Then when I try this, it returns false. Why?

```
console.log 'Factory' of Folds
```

The following is returning "function Folds() {}"

```
console.log Folds
```

I can't call Folds.Factory.create() because Folds.Factory is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `in` is for arrays (and array-like objects); `of` compiles to JavaScript's `in`. So what you want is

```
console.log 'Factory' of Folds
```

That's not the core problem, though: The core problem is that the `public` method you're using actually defines a property with the given name on the class' *prototype*, as the line

```
Object.defineProperty @prototype, name, config
```

tells us. So what you *really* want is

```
console.log 'Factory' of Folds.prototype  # should be true
```

which means that the `Factory` method will be available as a property of every `Folds` instance.

Comment: Whoa, great catch, I feel a bit ashamed. But unfortunately it's a classic case of "so it wouldn't work even if I had my issue figured out", and I still have my issue. For instance I couldn't and still can't call Folds.Factory.create() since Factory is undefined.

Comment: Oh thanks, now I get it! I guess it's what I get for moving on to CoffeeScript without deeply understanding JavaScript's prototypal object orientation.

Comment: And so I guess this means I should be defining "@public 'Factory'" not on Folds, which is a 'static class', but on _Folds instead, since that's my real singleton instance class? Or maybe I should have a '@static' method for defining a property on the class itself, not on the prototype, when it's a static class I won't be instancing?

Comment: Yeah, definitely define an `@static` method that does `Object.defineProperty @` instead of `@prototype`.